# Is there a Good and Working Bug reporting library in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I was looking for a bug reporting library for my c# project, Googling this Query yielded a list, 
but most of the results were irrelevant for me, i found a question (almost exact): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224/good-crash-reporting-library-in-c
But this didn't help,

Is There any recommendation for such library?,

PS: i am looking for good and **working** libraries

Comment: @user I don't get it : are you looking for a bug reporting system ? or an error api ? why would you use a bug reporting api ?

Comment: Please specify why the solutions posted in that question don't help you.

Comment: How exactly do you define "good" this is a very subjective question. In my eyes BugzScout is good and I would assume it works.  BugTrap also seems to (still) work.

Comment: Look at this

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224/good-crash-reporting-library-in-c-sharp/10597805#10597805][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224/good-crash-reporting-library-in-c-sharp/10597805#10597805

Comment: What's about ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) and EventSource for .NET 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you mean by bug reporting library, but perhaps Elmah can help you? Elmah logs all unhandled exceptions in an asp.net application.

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: It's an exception reporting system / api. Bug and exception are 2 differents things : you can have a bug without exception and an exception without bug. In fact a bug with an exception can be seen as a very defensive way of developing (IMHO)

Comment: Yeah, true, i know. But I thought i'd post it anyway. Maybe the author of the question doen't know Elmah and is already helped a bit by it.